# VBA Error 13 : Why i become this error although it worked for other varialbles at the same code

Tags: excel, vba, types, mismatch

I need to filter some columns(string and numbers). I defined var as variant, sArray() as String.
I become an Error type 13 (only for sArray 4,5) here:

```
   ReDim sArray4(1 To UBound(var4))  & ReDim sArray5(1 To UBound(var5))
```

var4 is a string/variant  for exp "Consulting & Supprot" but UBound(var4)  deliver a missmatch 
I don't understand that  var1, var2 and var3 are also like var4 2D variant and ReDim sArray2(1 To UBound(var2)) ... works fine.

any help appreciated :)

PS: new at VBA & it is not my Code

I already saw the questions related to this error. I find nothing helpful

```
Dim Pfad1 As String
Dim Bezeichnung As Variant
Umsatzdatenbank = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Pfad1 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Umsatz").Cells(5, 5)
Dim range1, range2, range3, range4, range5 As Range
lastoffice = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastbez = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastbez2 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastoffice2 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set range1 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("B3:B" & lastbez)
Set range2 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("E3:E" & lastoffice)
Set range4 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("C3:C" & lastbez2)
Set range5 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("F3:F" & lastoffice)
Dim var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 As Variant
Dim sArray1(), sArray2(), sArray3(), sArray4(), sArray5()  As String
Dim i As Long
var1 = range1.Value
ReDim sArray1(1 To UBound(var1))
For i = 1 To (UBound(var1))
    sArray1(i) = var1(i, 1)
Next

var2 = range2.Value
ReDim sArray2(1 To UBound(var2))
For i = 1 To (UBound(var2))
    sArray2(i) = var2(i, 1)
Next
var4 = range4.Value
ReDim sArray4(1 To UBound(var4))
For i = 1 To (UBound(var4))
    sArray4(i) = var4(i, 1)
Next

var5 = range5.Value
ReDim sArray5(1 To UBound(var5))
For i = 1 To (UBound(var5))
    sArray5(i) = var5(i, 1)
Next

Workbooks.Open Pfad1
ActiveSheet.Name = ("Quelldatei")
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "FSS"
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Workbooks.Open Pfad1
ActiveSheet.Name = ("Quelldatei")
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "GMS"
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("K1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Worksheets("FSS").Range("$A$1:$AA$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=sArray1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Worksheets("FSS").Range("$A$2:$AA$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Worksheets("FSS").Range("$A$1:$AA$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=sArray2, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Worksheets("FSS").Range("$A$2:$AA$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Comment: `Dim sArray1(), sArray2(), sArray3(), sArray4(), sArray5()  As String` is invalid it only declares sArray5() as string, the rest is declared as variant. You should write as: `Dim sArray1() as String, sArray2() as string....`

Comment: To add to @Luuklag's comment, `Dim range1, range2, range3, range4, range5 As Range` only declares `range5` as a `Range`.  All others are `Variant`.  You have to be explicit when declaring the types: `Dim range1 as Range, range2 as Range, ...`

Comment: @Luuklag not quite. `sArray1...5()` are all arrays still - only, they're `Variant` arrays except `sArray5()` which is a `String` array. Fixing that makes the intent more explicit, which is good, but won't cause a type mismatch in e.g. `sArray1(i) = var1(i, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ReDim sArray4(1 To UBound(var4))
> ```

The problem is `UBound(var4)`, because `var4` is a 2D variant array, as per this instruction:

```
var4 = range4.Value
```

Because `range4` contains mutiple cells, as per this instruction:

```
Set range4 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("C3:C" & lastbez2)
```

There are two solutions.

One would be to specify the dimension in `UBound(var4)`:

```
ReDim sArray4(1 To UBound(var4, 1))
```

Another would be, since `range4` is a single-column range, to make `var4` a single-dimentional array, using `Application.Transpose`:

```
var4 = Application.Transpose(range4.Value)
```

With `var4` being a single-dimension array, `UBound(var4)` will work as expected - note that making `var4` a single-dimension array removes the need for explicitly specifying a subscript for the 2nd dimension here:

```
sArray4(i) = var4(i, 1)
```

...and leaving it in would cause a *subscript out of range* error.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. I don't understand var1, var2 and var3 are also like var4   2D variant and                                                                                                          ReDim sArray2(1 To UBound(var2))  ... works fine